# Should I use spark-submit if using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, spark-submit

What is the purpose of spark submit? From what I can see it is just adding properties and jars to the classpath. 
If I am using spring boot can I avoid using spark-submit, and just package a fat jar with all the properties I want spark.master etc...

Can ppl see any downside to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recently I met same case - and also try to stick to spring boot exec jar which unfortunately failed finally, but I was close to end. the state when I gave up was - spring boot jar built without spark/hadoop libs included, and i was running it on a cluster with -Dloader.path='spark/hadoop libs list extracted from SPARK_HOME and HADOOP_HOME on cluster'. I ended up using 2d option - build fat jar with shaded plugin and running it as usual jar by spark submit which seems to be a bit strange solution but still works ok